# How to identify multiple instances of WPF windows?

Tags: testcomplete

I am testing a WPF application. One of my testcase involves opening 2 instances of my application and compare some elements.
I can see that when I start each application instance, they have been numbered as 1 and 2.

```
var firstwindow= Sys.process("my App" ,1).WPFObject("HwndSource:AppWindow", WindowTitle).WPFObject("AppWindow", "WindowTitle", 1);

var secondwindow=Sys.process("my App" ,2).WPFObject("HwndSource:AppWindow", WindowTitle).WPFObject("AppWindow", "WindowTitle", 1);
```

So above are the two windows of my 2 application instances  that I would want to compare.

Is there any other way of referring to these multiple instances windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any problems using this way to reference windows? It seems to be quite straightforward and clear, why are you searching for another approach?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for looking into this. This approach works.But sometimes when my first app instance takes some time load and start, the second app instance takes the place of first app and gets the numbering 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is that you want to differentiate your processes not by their TestComplete ids, you need to find another way to distinguish them. For example, if the processes have some differences in their command line (e.g. parameters), you can get a process by its command line (c:\MyAppFolder\MyApp.exe -firstAppParameter):

```
var firstApp = Sys.FindChild("CommandLine", "*-firstAppParameter*");
```

If you are using Name Mapping, you can add the CommandLine parameter to the process mapping scheme and use the same approach with wildcards.